# jQuery Validate: Rule active for multiple radiobuttons only fires for the first one

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**You can run the code snippet at the bottom: The attachment happens correctly N times, but the actual method only executes once. This problem happens in a dynamically generated form.**

I have the following custom rule in jQuery Validator that applies to all radiobuttons on my form.

```
    // Destroy and re-initialize Form Validator (dynamically repopulated form)
    var validator = $('#activityQuestionsForm').validate();
    validator.destroy();
    $(form).validate({ .. }); // with configuration

    // Define custom validation method
    $.validator.addMethod('childAnswersVisible', function(value, element) {
         // .. Custom function goes here.. returns true/false
    });

    ...

    // Attach custom validation method to all radiobuttons
    if ($(element).is("#activityQuestionsForm input[type=radio]")) {
        $(element).rules("add", {childAnswersVisible : true});
    }
```

I have 3 radiobuttons. When the form is created I see that the `rules("add")` attachment correctly executes 3 times. So all 3 radiobuttons now have the custom validation attached.

I also have a breakpoint inside my custom validation definition in `addMethod` (see above, where I have `.. Custom function goes here.. returns true/false`), and on Form Submission, I see that that block **only executes once** -- for the very first radiobutton. Does anyone know why? When submitting the form, I expect that breakpoint to be hit 3 times, one per each radiobutton, to make the decision for each of the radiobuttons.

```js
// Construct a dynamic form with 3 radiobuttons
var html = '<form id="activityQuestionsForm">' + 
           '   <input type="radio" name="choices" id="62"> 62 <br> ' +
           '   <input type="radio" name="choices" id="63"> 63 <br> ' +
           '   <input type="radio" name="choices" id="64"> 64 <br> ' +
           '<input type="submit">' + 
           '</form>';
           
$(html).appendTo('body');

$.validator.addMethod('childAnswersVisible', function(value, element) {
   alert('Running custom method');
   return true;
});

$('#activityQuestionsForm').validate();

$("#activityQuestionsForm input[type=radio]").each(function(index) {
   $(this).rules("add", {childAnswersVisible : true});
   alert('Attached custom method for: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please construct a working demo or at least provide enough code for such.  I don't see any markup and you've left out all the functions and configurations.  How is anybody supposed to know what you're doing wrong or test this out?

Comment: Sparky, a new snippet is attached. You can run it. If you notice, the rule is correctly attached N times, but the actual validation method only runs once. That's the problem. You can scroll through the 3 alerts and then 1 alert only.

Comment: The rule is only attached to first element because that's how this plugin is written.  You must wrap the `.rules()` method within an `.each()` in order to attach it to all matched elements in the selector.  See my answer below.

Comment: Sparky, sorry, I'm a bit confused again: in my snippet, I **do** wrap `.rules()` in `.each()`. It's there: `$("#activityQuestionsForm input[type=radio]").each(function(index) {
   $(this).rules("add", {childAnswersVisible : true});`. So why is it not working in the snippet? Disregard the first sample, the actual snippet has the right loop, and yet it's still not executing.

Comment: jQuery Validate only uses the `name` attribute for validation, NOT `id`.  Since all three radio buttons have the same `name`, this group of buttons is considered as ONE input.  Therefore, everything is working as expected and you've applied the rule to the same input three times.  If they are unique and you are allowed to select any/all of them, then they will need different `names`.  https://jsfiddle.net/fo1jbu0v/

Comment: Example:  ONE input:  `name="gender"`... radio button choices:  male, female, other.

Comment: Ahh that's the answer. Thanks, I believe that's the underlying problem here.

Comment: Original answer was updated for your edits.

Comment: I appreciate it. The relevant part is the "EDIT" so that should be first, with perhaps the other stuff deleted. As soon as that's clarified/simplified I can accept. Thanks again. The issue was the "name" on multiple radio buttons being part of a group as you said.

Comment: I will make an adjustment to the answer.  However, I answered the question exactly as you originally posted it.   Completely changing the question later is inheriently unfair to anyone that takes the time to answer.  Effectively, you've received two answers for one.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

All three radio buttons have the same `name` attribute....

```
var html = '<form id="activityQuestionsForm">' + 
       '   <input type="radio" name="choices" id="62"> 62 <br> ' +
       '   <input type="radio" name="choices" id="63"> 63 <br> ' +
       '   <input type="radio" name="choices" id="64"> 64 <br> ' +
       '<input type="submit">' + 
       '</form>';
```

Therefore, [this plugin considers this group of radios as a single input for this form](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations).  So applying the rule to each of the three buttons is redundant; the validation rule and message is for all three buttons at once, not individually.  The actual validation will result in a single message for the grouping of buttons.

[If you need each button to have it's own validation, then each one needs a unique `name`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations).

```
var html = '<form id="activityQuestionsForm">' + 
       '   <input type="radio" name="choices1" id="62"> 62 <br> ' +
       '   <input type="radio" name="choices2" id="63"> 63 <br> ' +
       '   <input type="radio" name="choices3" id="64"> 64 <br> ' +
       '<input type="submit">' + 
       '</form>';
```

See:  [jsfiddle.net/fo1jbu0v/](https://jsfiddle.net/fo1jbu0v/)

[Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations):

> Mandated: A `name` attribute is required for all input elements
>   needing validation, and the plugin will not work without this. A
>   `name` attribute **must also be unique to the form**, as this is how the
>   plugin keeps track of all input elements. However, **each group of radio
>   or checkbox elements will share the same `name`** since the value of
>   this grouping represents a single piece of the form data.

---

**OP's original code before editing:**

```
// Attach custom validation method to all radiobuttons
if ($(element).is("#activityQuestionsForm input[type=radio]")) {
    $(element).rules("add", {childAnswersVisible : true});
}
```

There is no reason to put `.rules()` insides a conditional when you can simply attach it directly to your jQuery selector.

```
$("#activityQuestionsForm input[type=radio]").rules("add", {childAnswersVisible : true});
```

Regardless, your whole problem is because this plugin's methods only attach to the *first* element when multiple elements are selected.

The proper solution is to wrap it up in an `.each()` in order to attach this rule to all matched elements.

```
$("#activityQuestionsForm input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {childAnswersVisible : true});
});
```

Reference<sup>1</sup>:  [jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page)

<sup>1</sup> - Even though the documentation is specifically about the `.validate()` method, this concept applies to all methods provided by this plugin including `.rules()`.

Comment: That's what I did. You can see in my new snippet that I correctly attach it N times, and my alerts prove that. However, the underlying method still only runs once, which the other alert also shows.

Comment: I apologize, the snippet has the Each loop, and yet it's still not working. I updated my answer to reflect the latest snippet.